# Seleccionar dos rangos de fechas de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito una consulta con los siguientes datos

```
dly_accountNumber        // GROUP BY
dly_accountName         
balance_Inicial_debito   // suma de los debitos hasta 2019-06-30
balance_inicial_credito  // suma de los creditos hasta 2019-06-30
mov_mes_debito           // suma de los debitos de julio 2019
mov_mes_credito          // suma de los creditos de julio 2019
balance_final_debito     // (BI.DB - BI.CR) + (MVTO.DB - MVTO.CR) POSITIVO
balance_final_credito    // (BI.DB - BI.CR) + (MVTO.DB - MVTO.CR) NEGATIVO
```

tengo la siguiente tabla donde se guardan todas las transacciones

```
CREATE TABLE `adm_account_daily` (
  `dly_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dly_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_accountId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_accountNumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_accountName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_voucherType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_voucherId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_voucherPrefix` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_voucherNum` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_affectedDoc` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_db` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dly_cr` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dly_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

No tengo problema armando las consultas una a una

Saldos iniciales

```
SELECT 
    dly_date
    dly_accountNumber,
    dly_accountName,
    SUM(dly_db) AS balance_Inicial_debito, SUM(dly_cr) AS balance_Inicial_credito
FROM
    adm_account_daily
WHERE
    dly_date <= '2019-06-31'
GROUP BY dly_accountId
ORDER BY dly_accountNumber
```

mivimiento del mes

```
SELECT 
    dly_date,
    dly_accountNumber,
    dly_accountName,
    SUM(dly_db) AS totaldb,
    SUM(dly_cr) AS totalcr
FROM
    adm_account_daily
WHERE
    dly_date BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'
GROUP BY dly_accountId
ORDER BY dly_accountNumber
```

he pensado armar el informe en una tabla nueva (adm_account_major) con todos los datos, sin embargo, creo que se puede en una sola consulta pero no se como hacer los dos `SELECT` de fechas y la operacion del balance final en la misma consulta.

Answer (score 2):

La consulta queda asi:

```
SELECT 
    dly_accountNumber,
    dly_accountName,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN dly_date <= '2019-07-31' THEN dly_db
        ELSE 0
    END) AS init_balance_db,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN dly_date <= '2019-07-31' THEN dly_cr
        ELSE 0
    END) AS init_balance_cr,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN dly_date BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31' THEN dly_db
        ELSE 0
    END) AS mvto_db,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN dly_date BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31' THEN dly_cr
        ELSE 0
    END) AS mvto_cr
FROM
    adm_account_daily
GROUP BY dly_accountId
ORDER BY dly_accountNumber
```

Las operaciones del balance final se hacen en el codigo del informe.